# How to customize Lucene.NET to search for words with symbols without case-sensitivity (e.g. "C#" or ".net")?

Tags: c#, .net, lucene, lucene.net

The standard analyzer does not work. From what I can understand, it changes this to a search for `c` and `net`

The `WhitespaceAnalyzer` would work but it's case sensitive.

The general rule is search should work like Google so hoping it's a configuration thing considering `.net`, `c#` have been out there for a while or there's a workaround for this.

Per the suggestions below, I tried the custom `WhitespaceAnalyzer` but then if the keywords are separated by a comma and no-space are not handled correctly e.g.

```
java,.net,c#,oracle
```

will not be returned while searching which would be incorrect.

I came across `PatternAnalyzer` which is used to split the tokens but can't figure out how to use it in this scenario.

I'm using `Lucene.Net 3.0.3` and `.NET 4.0`

Comment: is your domain source-code? Or are those just examples?

Comment: @phani those are just examples

Answer (score -2, accepted):

for others who might be looking for an answer as well

the final answer turned out be to create a custom TokenFilter and a custom Analyzer using
that token filter along with Whitespacetokenizer, lowercasefilter etc., all in all about 30 lines of code, i will create a blog post and post the link here when i do, have to create a blog first !

Comment: Hi any chance you could publish it on a Gist? It sounds very useful

Answer (score 7):

Write your own custom analyzer class similar to `SynonymAnalyzer` in [Lucene.Net – Custom Synonym Analyzer](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/lucene_custom_analyzer.aspx). Your override of `TokenStream` could solve this by pipelining the stream using `WhitespaceTokenizer` and `LowerCaseFilter`.

Remember that your indexer and searcher need to use the same analyzer.

**Update: Handling multiple comma-delimited keywords**

If you only need to handle unspaced comma-delimited keywords for *searching*, not indexing then you could convert the search expression `expr` as below.

```
expr = expr.Replace(',', ' ');
```

Then pass `expr` to the `QueryParser`. If you want to support other delimiters like ';' you could do it like this:

```
var terms = expr.Split(new char[] { ',', ';'} );
expr = String.Join(" ", terms);
```

But you also need to check for a phrase expression like "sybase,c#,.net,oracle" (expression includes the quote " chars) which should not be converted (the user is looking for an exact match):

```
expr = expr.Trim();
if (!(expr.StartsWith("\"") && expr.EndsWith("\"")))
{
    expr = expr.Replace(',', ' ');
}
```

The expression might include both a phrase and some keywords, like this:

```
"sybase,c#,.net,oracle" server,c#,.net,sybase
```

Then you need to parse and translate the search expression to this:

```
"sybase,c#,.net,oracle" server c# .net sybase
```

If you also need to handle unspaced comma-delimited keywords for *indexing* then you need to parse the text for unspaced comma-delimited keywords and store them in a distinct field eg. `Keywords` (which must be associated with your custom analyzer). Then your search handler needs to convert a search expression like this:

```
server,c#,.net,sybase
```

to this:

```
Keywords:server Keywords:c# Keywords:.net, Keywords:sybase
```

or more simply:

```
Keywords:(server, c#, .net, sybase)
```

Comment: tried that but then it does not recognize keywords like oracle,.net,c#,sybase etc. which are done by google - the golden standard for our users as it were, will look more info perhaps customizing the tokenizer if possible

Comment: this is needed for searching AND indexing, interesting idea about parsing into a separate field but that'd be more work considering we'd have to handle say .net4/ .net4.5 etc. rather than a .net* (silent) search etc. If i can't figure out a way to customize the tokenizer then will have to do something like this

Answer (score 4):

Use the `WhitespacerAnalyzer` and chain it with a [LowerCaseFilter](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_0_0/api/core/org/apache/lucene/analysis/LowerCaseFilter.html).

Use the same chain at search and index time. by converting everything to lower case, you actually make it case insensitive.

According to your problem description, that should work and be simple to implement.